# При клике меняется содержимое span для определенного класса

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".job_link").click(function(){        
        $(this).parents(".job_item").find(".job_desc").toggleClass("job_hidden");
        $(".arrow span").text(&darr;);
    });
});
```

Хочу чтобы при клике содержимое span менялось, по умолчанию там стоит ↑
А нужно чтобы при клике оно менялось на ↓ при повторном клике обратно на ↑

Как такое сделать? Сейчас это код не рабочий, потому что .arrow span не понимает для какого класса почему-то.

Добавил разметку:

```
        <div class="job_item">
            <div class="job_title">
                <a class="job_link" href="javascript:void(0);"> <b><?=$name?> </b></a>
<span class="arrow" style="cursor: pointer; color:#911B1D;">&uarr;</span>
            </div>
            <div class='job_desc job_hidden'>
                <p>
                <?=$text?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `.arrow span` - не совсем правильно для конкретного случая, тут нужно писать `span.arrow` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путем небольшого усложнения разметки можно сделать так:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .job_item span.up,
    .job_item span.down  {
        cursor: pointer;
        color:#911B1D;
        display: none;
    }
    .job_item .job_desc {
        display: none;
    }
    .job_item .up span.up,
    .job_item .down span.down  {
        display: inline;
    }
    .job_item .down .job_desc {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
...
<div class="job_item">
    <div class="up">
        <div class="job_title">
            <a class="job_link" href="javascript:void(0);"> <b><?=$name?> </b></a>
            <span class="up">&uarr;</span>
            <span class="down">&darr;</span>
        </div>
        <div class='job_desc'>
            <p><?=$text?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $(".job_link").click(
                    function () {
                        var o = $(this).parent().parent();

                        o.attr(
                            "class",
                            (o.attr("class") == "up") ?
                                "down" :
                                "up"
                        );
                    }
                );
            }
        );      
</script>
```

P.S. Можно посмотреть как это выглядит здесь: http://jsfiddle.net/chernomyrdin/cEsad/

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо.

Comment: В принципе можно сделать по-проще с точки зрения разметки, в примере я пытался максимально сохранить то, что у Вас было. Можно сделать:

    <div class="job_item">
        <div class="up">
           <a class="up" href="#!up"><u>...</u> <span>&uarr;</span></a>
           <a class="down" href="#!down"><u>...</u> <span>&darr;</span></a>
           <p>....</p>
        </div>
    </div>

Так более прозрачный под получается, хотя я не заню что там в `<p>` будет выводиться, там могут быть ньюансы

Comment: Первый пример отлично подошел, в <p> будет самое разное.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [$.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), и в него поместите реакцию на клик.

Comment: Сейчас это код нерабочий, потому что `.arrow span` не понимает для какого класса почему-то.

Comment: Ну да, надо что-то вроде такого, только с `.arrow span` разобраться надо (не видя разметки, непонятно, как).

<pre>
$(document).ready(
 function(){
  $(".job_link").toogle(
   function(){
    $(this).parents(".job_item").find(".job_desc").toggleClass("job_hidden");
    $(".arrow span").text(&darr;);
   },
   function(){
    $(this).parents(".job_item").find(".job_desc").toggleClass("job_hidden");
    $(".arrow span").text(&uarr;);
   }
  );
 }
);
</pre>

Comment: Добавил разметку.

Comment: Надо местами поменять: span .arrow.  Ну да, выше уже написали :)